# Why does creating a pdf by iteration from a list of argument fail with for/lapply?

Tags: r, iteration, nested-lists

I am relatively new to R, and it seems that, despite my loops working properly otherwise, I am unable to iterate trough a list to create pdf: 
For instance this code

**(Variables & libraries:)**

Libraries

```
library(Seurat)
```

The different markers are lists of chain of characters like DenditicCells:

```
DendriticCells <- c("Kmo", "Flt3", "Ccr7", "Ccl17", "Irf8","Xcr1","Cd209")

Markers <- list(Neurons, Oligo, OPC, AstroPro, Astro, OligoPro, Pericytes, ImmuneCells, GeneOfInterest, Lymphatics, Vein, Arteries, cappilaries, Microglial, Macrophages, ThCells, Tcells, Bcells, Granulocytes, DendriticCells, CPMicrogenes, TNK, migDCs )
Markers <- setNames(Markers, c("Neurons", "Oligo", "OPC", "AstroPro", "Astro", "OligoPro", "Pericytes", "ImmuneCells", "GeneOfInterest", "Lymphatics", "Vein", "Arteries", "cappilaries", "Microglial", "Macrophages", "ThCells", "Tcells", "Bcells", "Granulocytes", "DendriticCells", "CPMicrogenes", "TNK", "migDCs" ))
```

**Code**

```
pdf(paste0("Run5/DotPlot6", names(Markers[x]),"Subset4.jpeg"))
DotPlot(Subset4, assay = "SCT"  ,features =Markers[[x]], dot.scale = 8)
dev.off()
```

Works and creates a pdf, but this code:

```
Ret4 <- function(x){
  pdf(paste0("Run5/DotPlot6", names(Markers[x]),"Subset4.jpeg"))
  try(DotPlot(Subset4, assay = "SCT"  ,features =Markers[[x]], dot.scale = 8))
  dev.off()
}
for(i in 1:length(Markers))Ret4(i)
```

fails after a perfectly normal execution. I have tried variation using different format, lapply, map, and it does not work. I do not understand why this execution fails...

How can i iterate through this? In this case, Markers is a list of list of 24 elements.

Thanks a lot 
Jean

Comment: Hi Jean and welcome to SO. So `pdf = jpeg`? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible, since we don't have `Neurons`, `Oligo`, etc.  When I replace your `DotPlot` call with `plot(x)`, it works fine for me.  So you've got some problem in the code you're not showing us.  Please post a self-contained example if that's not enough of a hint to figure it out on your own.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the Seurat package, there is a dev.off problem, resolved by allocating the plot to a variable and calling it within the file creation. In the documentation they always called it after allocating it. 
Thanks, Problem resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
Ret5 <- function(x, Markers, Subset, nameSubset){ p <- DotPlot(Subset, assay = "SCT" ,features =Markers[[x]], dot.scale = 8) 
png(paste("Run5/Subset/", as.character(x),names(Markers[[x]]),".jpeg", sep = "")) 
print(p) 
dev.off() } 
for(x in c(1:length(Markers))){ Ret5(x, Markers, Subset1, "Subset1")}
```